# User_id is nil on rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `user` model and a `shout` model. I am trying to have a user be associated with a shout. I did not make this association upon creation of the shouts table so I had to run a new migration. Below is my table, the models of each, and the output when from my console I run a command to try and find the user_id of a shout. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

schema:

```
create_table "shouts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "title"
    t.text    "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  add_index "shouts", ["user_id"], name: "index_shouts_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",           null: false
    t.string   "password_digest", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password_digest, presence: true
  has_many :shouts
end
```

Shout Model:

```
class Shout < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Shout Controller:

class ShoutsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
        @new_shout = Shout.new
    end

def create
    @new_shout = Shout.new(shouts_params)


    if @new_shout.user_id == nil
        render new_shout_path
    elsif @new_shout.save
        redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
        render new_shout_path
    end
end

private

def shouts_params
    params.require(:shout).permit(:title, :description, :user_id)
end
```

end

Some test code:

```
> Shout.find(4)
> #<Shout id: 4, title: "four", description: "four", user_id: nil>
```

Creating an instance of user from the console, working:

```
> User.first.shouts.create(title: 'four', description: 'four')
>[["title", "four"], ["description", "four"], ["user_id", 1]
```

Migration file:

```
class AddUserRefToShouts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :shouts, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your migration look like? 2) Where (if any place) are you assigning a shout to a user or vise-versa? It looks like you have existing shouts in the DB, then added the shouts.user_id column in a migration, but never filled in the user_id for those shouts.

Comment: Can you show how the `shout` record is being created? You have to create the association. e.g. `user.shouts.create(title: 'four', description: 'four')` which should assign the user_id.

Comment: @d_ethier that returns `User.shouts.create(title: 'four', description: 'four')
NoMethodError: undefined method `shouts' for #<Class:0x007fef027c5670>`

Comment: @ZachDennis I added my migration file for reference. 2) I thought of that as I was troubleshooting so I shutdown my server, reset my db, created a user and shout and it was still returning nil.

Comment: @Jbur43, you want to call `shouts.create` on an instance of User, not on the User class itself. This is what @d_ethier is suggesting. Otherwise, you would have to explicitly pass in `user/user_id` when creating the Shout. E.g. `user = User.create ; user.shouts.create(title: 'four', description: 'four')` OR `user = User.create ; Shout.create(user: user)`

Comment: @ZachDennis The point of your comment was to call shouts.create not on User class but its instance, which is absolutely right. Just wanted to add that `user = User.create` wouldn't work without passwing email & password as it won't pass through the validations specified in User model.

Comment: @ZachDennis I see what you're saying, and when I do call it on an instance, it works, I added that above. Still not sure what it is not picking up the the user_id of the creator of the shout when I am signed into my application and creating shouts.

Comment: Because no one wrote any code to make that happen - others have shown you what that code needs to be like.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I thought that adding the reference of a shout to a user_id would then create a shout on an instance of a user. I'm just uncertain of what code needs to be added to the rails app to make this function

Comment: when you create a shout you need to specify a user_id, either explicitly or by using the association ( some_user.shouts.create). Change every place where you create shouts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple admittedly hacky options (but they'll work) if you don't want to follow the approach suggested in the comments. You could pass the user_id as a hidden field so it'll be included in the params or you can expressly set it in the create action.

If you want to pass as a hidden field, on your shout form add:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

Alternatively, if you want to handle in your create action:

```
def create
  @shout = Shout.new(shout_params)
  @shout.user_id = current_user.id
  @shout.save
end
```